# Is it possible to use multiple overlaping math/data curves inside one row?

Tags: javascript, diagram, timing-diagram

I want to recreate something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357358/how-to-plot-ft-gt-values-as-a-row-in-timing-diagramm) multyple functions, multiple states per row in [WaveDrom](https://github.com/wavedrom/wavedrom) like they [do in PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/timing-diagram):

[image]

So to have:

1. Multiple math/data functions per row
2. Scales for that data/functions

How to do such thing in [wavedrom](https://wavedrom.com/tutorial.html)?

Comment: Timing diagrams don't have functions with numeric ranges. It doesn't look like you can overlap timing diagrams either. You appear to have chosen a dependency that isn't capable of what you're asking to do.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: For example in [PlantUML](https://plantuml.com/timing-diagram) they kind-of do. At least the top multiple states based one...

Comment: Yes, that's PlantUML, a completely unrelated format for timing diagrams. WaveDrom uses WaveJSON, which does not appear to have support for multiple states.